# Convert 24 hour time to 12 hour time in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Converting the hour seems to take a lot of work... there must be a simpler way.

```
  <xsl:variable name="hour12">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$hour24 &lt; 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="12 + $hour24" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$hour24 = 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="12" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$hour24 = 12">
        <xsl:value-of select="$hour24" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$hour24 &gt; 12">
        <xsl:value-of select="$hour24 - 12" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$hour24" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh...I love how boolean values equal 0 or 1. It makes life so much easier...

```
<xsl:variable name="hour12">
    <xsl:value-of select="$hour24 - (12 * ($hour24 > 12)) + (12 * ($hour24 = 0))" />`
</xsl:variable>
```

And for the a/p identifier

```
<xsl:variable name="ap">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring('ap', 1 + ($hour24 >= 12), 1)" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Pretty neat solution. If your processor supports XSLT 2.0 you might want to look at the format-time() function. It allows you flexible format a xs:time value which you can create from a string value by calling xs:time($timevariable).

Comment: Why, why, why do we keep seeing this `<variable><value-of/></variable>` nonsense? It should be `<xsl:variable name='n' select='expression'/>`.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I started with more than a single value, and reduced to this.  Sorry for not taking the last step.

Answer (score 0):

**For the time conversion, here is something which I find simpler**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="time/text()">
  <xsl:variable name="vZ" select="(.+12) mod 12"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$vZ - ($vZ -12)*($vZ=0)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 <time>-3</time>
 <time>0</time>
 <time>7</time>
 <time>12</time>
 <time>17</time>
 <time>24</time>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
   <time>9</time>
   <time>12</time>
   <time>7</time>
   <time>12</time>
   <time>5</time>
   <time>12</time>
</t>
```

**For am/pm (if my understanding for the edge cases is correct) we add this code**:

```
  <xsl:variable name="vNorm" select=
  "not(. >= 0)*(24 +.)
  +
   (. >=0 and not(. = 24))*.
  +
   not(. = 24)
   "/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$vPeriods[1+($vNorm>=12)]"/>
```

**The complete transformation becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:timePeriods>
  <p>am</p>
  <p>pm</p>
 </my:timePeriods>

 <xsl:variable name="vPeriods" select=
 "document('')/*/my:timePeriods/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="time/text()">
  <xsl:variable name="vZ" select="(.+12) mod 12"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$vZ - ($vZ -12)*($vZ=0)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vNorm" select=
  "not(. >= 0)*(24 +.)
  +
   (. >=0 and not(. = 24))*.
  +
   not(. = 24)
   "/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$vPeriods[1+($vNorm>=12)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when applied to the same XML document (above) the result is**:

```
<t>
   <time>9pm</time>
   <time>12am</time>
   <time>7am</time>
   <time>12pm</time>
   <time>5pm</time>
   <time>12am</time>
</t>
```