# Converting Weekdays & Time in XML to JSON

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT 1.0 and need to convert following XML payload to JSON:

XML Payload:

```
 <OpeningTimes>
 <MondayOpen>00:00</MondayOpen>
  <MondayClosed>12:00</MondayClosed>
  <TuesdayOpen>13:00</TuesdayOpen>
  <TuesdayClosed>23:00</TuesdayClosed>
  <WednesdayOpen>00:00</WednesdayOpen>
  <WednesdayClosed>12:00</WednesdayClosed>
  <ThursdayOpen>01:00</ThursdayOpen>
  <ThursdayClosed>12:00</ThursdayClosed>
  <FridayOpen>01:00</FridayOpen>
  <FridayClosed>12:00</FridayClosed>
  <SaturdayOpen>01:00</SaturdayOpen>
  <SaturdayClosed>12:00</SaturdayClosed>
  <SundayOpen>01:00</SundayOpen>
  <SundayClosed>12:00</SundayClosed>
   </OpeningTimes>
```

Expected JSON output:

```
{
"opening_hours": {
"open_now": false,
"periods": [
{
"close": {
"day": 0,
"time": "1200"
},
"open": {
"day": 0,
"time": "0000"
}
},
{
"close": {
"day": 1,
"time": "2300"
},
"open": {
"day": 1,
"time": "1300"
}
},
...
...
...
    {
    "close": {
    "day": 6,
    "time": "1200"
    },
    "open": {
    "day": 6,
    "time": "0000"
    }
    }
    ],
    "weekday_text": [
    "Monday: 12:00 AM – 12:00 PM",
    "Tuesday: 1:00 PM – 11:00 PM",
    "Wednesday: 12:00 AM – 12:00 PM",
    "Thursday: 12:00 AM – 12:00 PM",
    "Friday: 12:00 AM – 12:00 PM",
    "Saturday: 12:00 AM – 12:00 PM",
    "Sunday: 12:00 AM – 12:00 PM"
    ]
    }
    }
```

I tried using following for the initial part but don't think it is the best way:

```
<xsl:template match="au:MondayOpen">
        <day>
             <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
        </day>
        <time>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </time>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="au:MondayClosed">
        <day>
             <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
        </day>
        <time>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </time>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="au:TuesdayOpen">
        <day>
             <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
        </day>
        <time>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </time>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="au:TuesdayClosed">
        <day>
            <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
        </day>
        <time>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </time>
    </xsl:template>
```

and so on.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921564/convert-24-hour-time-to-12-hour-time-in-xslt) post about converting time, which I need in a later part of the JSON. Please ignore the given time values in output, it is just for an example.

Comment: So where is the question or problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input will always contain two entries for each day of the week, in the given order, you could eliminate code repetition by doing something like:

```
<xsl:template match="OpeningTimes">
    <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="*[position() mod 2 = 0]">
        <xsl:variable name="day" select="position() - 1" />
        <xsl:text>{"close":{"day": </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$day"/>
        <xsl:text>,"time":"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ':', '')"/>
        <xsl:text>"},"open":{"day": </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$day"/>
        <xsl:text>,"time":"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(preceding-sibling::*[1], ':', '')"/>
        <xsl:text>"}}</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

to produce:

```
[{"close":{"day": 0,"time":"1200"},"open":{"day": 0,"time":"0000"}},{"close":{"day": 1,"time":"2300"},"open":{"day": 1,"time":"1300"}},{"close":{"day": 2,"time":"1200"},"open":{"day": 2,"time":"0000"}},{"close":{"day": 3,"time":"1200"},"open":{"day": 3,"time":"0100"}},{"close":{"day": 4,"time":"1200"},"open":{"day": 4,"time":"0100"}},{"close":{"day": 5,"time":"1200"},"open":{"day": 5,"time":"0100"}},{"close":{"day": 6,"time":"1200"},"open":{"day": 6,"time":"0100"}}]
```

which after formatting becomes:

```
[
    {
        "close" : 
        {
            "day" : 0,
            "time" : "1200"
        },
        "open" : 
        {
            "day" : 0,
            "time" : "0000"
        }
    },
    {
        "close" : 
        {
            "day" : 1,
            "time" : "2300"
        },
        "open" : 
        {
            "day" : 1,
            "time" : "1300"
        }
    },
    {
        "close" : 
        {
            "day" : 2,
            "time" : "1200"
        },
        "open" : 
        {
            "day" : 2,
            "time" : "0000"
        }
    },
    {
        "close" : 
        {
            "day" : 3,
            "time" : "1200"
        },
        "open" : 
        {
            "day" : 3,
            "time" : "0100"
        }
    },
    {
        "close" : 
        {
            "day" : 4,
            "time" : "1200"
        },
        "open" : 
        {
            "day" : 4,
            "time" : "0100"
        }
    },
    {
        "close" : 
        {
            "day" : 5,
            "time" : "1200"
        },
        "open" : 
        {
            "day" : 5,
            "time" : "0100"
        }
    },
    {
        "close" : 
        {
            "day" : 6,
            "time" : "1200"
        },
        "open" : 
        {
            "day" : 6,
            "time" : "0100"
        }
    }
]
```

---

I suggest you ask separate questions about any additional tasks this might require. For converting time from 24-hour notation to 12-hour, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55924790/3016153

Comment: What if there are more elements in OpeningTimes? Can I set a position to start loop from 'MondayOpen'?

Comment: I would need to see an example of the input and understand its structure before answering that. Either edit your question or post a new one.